# Mongoid Relationship within an ActiveSupport::Concern Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, relationship, ruby-1.9.2

I'm trying to create a module that includes a polymorphic relationship with Mongoid. Simplified example:

```
module Scalable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    references_many :scales, :as => :scalable

    before_save :add_scale
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def add_scale
      self.scales.create
    end
  end
end

class Scale
  include Mongoid::Document

  referenced_in :scalable, :index => true
end

class ScalableModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Scalable
end
```

However, when I try to run something like `ScalableModel.create`, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `relations' for Scalable:Module
```

Is this not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the association in the module (from `Scalable` to `Scale`) is fine but the opposite half from `Scale` to `Scalable` is a problem. Thats because the target class is derived from the name of the association which is leading Mongoid to the `Scalable` module when you really need it to refer to the `ScalableModel` class. The error is then raised because Mongoid is treating the module as a model class.

At first I thought you would have to define both sides of the association in the Scalable included block but it turns out that you can fix the Scale side of the association by marking it as polymorphic.

There is one other issue, `self.scale.create` throws an exception because you cannot create a new child object until its parent has been saved. To work around that I just used `after_save`. This is what I came up with:

```
module Scalable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    references_many :scales, :as => :scalable
    after_save :add_scale                     # changed from before_save
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def add_scale
      self.scales.create
    end
  end
end

class Scale
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :scalable_model, :index => true, :polymorphic => true
end

class ScalableModel1
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Scalable
end

class ScalableModel2
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Scalable
end

s1 = ScalableModel1.create
s2 = ScalableModel2.create
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Steve, that worked perfectly. I was able to actually keep the callback as a before save by adding `:autosave => true` and changing the `self.scales.create` to `self.scales.build` in the callback.